# Access all holder views inside OnBindViewHolder in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I need to set the Clickable property of all the cards in a recycler view (with RecyclerView adapter class) to false once I click on any one of the cards. How do I do that? Setting holder.cardView.setClickable(false) only does it for the clicked one. How do I access all the cards in the view in OnBindViewHolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that due to the way `RecyclerView` lazy load the child view. The child views are only created and rendered when they are visible on the screen, other views are cleared to save memory.

You can do these to have the same effect:

1/ Create an overlay `FrameLayout` on top of your `RecyclerView`, set its `clickable` to true, then show/hide it when needed to prevent touch

```
<FrameLayout>
    <RecyclerView ... />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/overlay_view" 
        ...
        android:clickable="true" />
</FrameLayout>

cardItem.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    // The mOverlayView will intercept all the touch event on RecyclerView
    mOverlayView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
})
```

2/ Create a `boolean preventClick` variable, set it to true when you want to prevent user's click. Then check for this value in your item's OnClickListener.

Comment: Yes, I want only the existing child cards that are currently in view to be unclickable, for e.g., I have 4 cards visible at a time, so all of them should be unclickable, if I click any one of them to avoid double clicking

Comment: You want to prevent click on current visible items, but what if user scroll down a bit, visible items will changed, then click one of them. I may understand you wrong but the above approach are what I will do. An overlay view will intercept all the click if you make it visible when any card is clicked

Answer (score 0):

My idea is:

In your adapter class define:

```
public static SparseBooleanArray itemCardClickState = new SparseBooleanArray();
private int currentPlayingPosition = -1;
```

and in your viewHolder class:

```
  myCardItem..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        int prev = currentPlayingPosition;
                        currentPlayingPosition = position;
                        if (prev >= 0)
                            notifyItemChanged(prev); 
                          // refresh previously clicked item view
                        itemCardClickState .put(currentPlayingPosition, true);
                    }
                  });
```

and check the card state in onBinViewHoldee is true or false

Answer (score 0):

I found a long process which solves your problem with a clean code

Step 1 - Take your item click listener to the Activity with an interface. Add this code to your RecyclerView Adapter

```
private RecyclerViewItemClickListener recyclerViewItemClickListener;

public void setRecyclerViewItemClickListener(RecyclerViewItemClickListener recyclerViewItemClickListener) {
    this.recyclerViewItemClickListener = recyclerViewItemClickListener;
}

public interface RecyclerViewItemClickListener {
    void onClick(View v);
}
```

Step 2 - Make the click listener for your item in the ViewHolder, not in the onBindViewHolder

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recyclerViewItemClickListener.onClick(v);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In your Activity, use the interface to set click listener and on click override it again with a blank code.

```
adapter.setRecyclerViewItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do everything that should happen on click

            //then set a blank click listener
            adapter.setRecyclerViewItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I tested it and it works as you want it to

Answer (score 0):

Declare a `Integer` variable in adapter and assign the corresponding postion to which positioned view is enabled and compare the value in `bindItem` and enable, disable according. Also make sure to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when clicked.